# Returning derived class instance from a base class

Tags: c#, inheritance

The title may be unclear, but please look at the pattern below

```
public abstract class Animal
{

    public abstract Dog GetDog { get; }

    public abstract Cat GetCat { get; }

}

public class Dog : Animal
{

    public override Dog GetDog {
        get { return this; }
    }

    public override Cat GetCat {
        get { return null; }
    }

}
```

Is this considered a bad practice to have properties in the base class, return derived types. Or should I do something like

```
public abstract AnimalTypeEnum AnimalType { get; }
```

EDIT: Based on the comments, I guess I should be more clear on what I am trying to achieve. A new instance of the `Dog` or `Cat` class would be created by a separate function based on certain criteria and would then return `Animal` type to the caller. The calling method would check the type of the returned instance and use it accordingly.

```
public Animal CreateAnimal(string path)
{

    //Process the document in path and create either a new instance of dog or cat

    Dog dg = new Dog();

    return dg;

}
```

Comment: What's you're ultimate goal in doing this?

Comment: @user1556110 That doesn't really answer the question.  How will these methods actually be used?

Comment: Okay... but what's the point? Dog should not have a method to get a cat, even if it's returning null. What's wrong with `Animal dog = new Dog()`?

Comment: I would return the base class from a function and the method calling the function would then cast it to the relevant derived type

Comment: @user1556110 But if you are going to cast it eventually, won't that defeat the point of inheriting a base class?

Comment: It looks to me like you are trying to provide an alternative syntax for `Dog dog = animal as Dog;`. In general you should avoid your base class knowing about derived classes - otherwise to add a new derived class you have to change the base class - it's rather messy.

Comment: Why does dog need a method GetCat, or cat a method GetDog?  That's a quick sign that somethings not right with the design and prob a violation of lsp.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The calling method would check the type of the returned instance and use it accordingly.

There's your problem.  It's code smell to need to do that.  You should be able to treat whatever it is as just an object, rather than treating dogs and cats differently.

If you need to display the content of either animal, then override the `ToString` method on both classes and just call `ToString` on animal.  If you need to know the name of the dog or cat then add a `Name` property to `Animal`.  If at all possible you should be using polymorphism here so that whatever is using the object treads it as just an `Animal` and simply involves different things happening as a result of different implementations of the same method.

If you really, really do need to know whether the `Animal` is a `Dog` or a `Cat` then you can use the `is` or `as` operators; you don't need to add all of the code that you've shown in the OP.

Comment: The base class has a lot of functionality that is common to both the derived types, the derived types extend it by a little more. When  the `CreateAnimal` function is called either a `Cat` type or `Dog` type needs to be created dynamically and there is no way of knowing which type needs to be created before hand. So I would really need to return the minimum guaranteed type and also provide options if they want to do a little more.

Comment: @user1556110 Yes, the `CreateAnimal` method is fine; I'm not suggesting you change it.  I'm saying that you should be able to do whatever you need to do with the `Animal` that is returned without doing something that results in either a `Cat` or `Dog` instance.  While there may be a situation in which you *really* can't do that, you should be quite sure before going down that road.  If you do go down that road, as I said, you should use `is` or `as` rather than the construct you've created.

Comment: @user1556110 - Even assuming that you need to know whether it's a `Cat` or a `Dog` specifically, you could just replace whatever test you were thinking of using with `is`.

Comment: @bobson I agree on the `Is` part and I do not necessarily need to know whether it is a `Cat` or `Dog` to call methods on `Animal`, while I would need to know the type to call certain methods on derived types which are otherwise invalid for a different type. Are there any other approaches?

Comment: `if (animal is Cat) { ((Cat)animal).Meow(); } else if (animal is Dog) { ((Dog)animal).Bark(); } else { throw new TypeException(); }`.   I still don't understand why you can't move the creation logic out of `CreateAnimal()` into your calling code, though.

Comment: @Bobson You've just shown a perfect example of what you shouldn't be doing.  Rather than having a cat meow or a dog bark, you should add something like `Speak` to `Animal` which either barks or meows depending on the type of the derived class.

Comment: @user1556110 My whole point is that you shouldn't have methods only on the derived class that you need to use in this context.  If you're creating the animal from a general method then any code using it shouldn't need to do something that's specific to just one.  In most cases this means that whatever function you want to use should simply be defined in `Animal`, even if the implementation for dog or cat doesn't do anything.

Comment: @Servy - Agreed.  Using that code would be *bad*, but using the OP's code would be *worse*.  It's a situation that desperately calls for refactoring.

Comment: @Servy What if `Cat` needs a method called `LookCute` that is just not valid for `Dog`. Typically, should I still define it in the `Animal` class. I am not challenging, I am just trying to learn and I don't understand the negative vote.

Comment: @user1556110 If you need to have a `LookCute` method for just cats then you shouldn't be calling it on an object that's returned from a method that may or may not be a cat.  You should only be calling `LookCute` on something that, from the start, you know will be able to look cute.

Answer (score 23):

If you only want the animal you are deriving from you can do this:

```
public abstract class Animal<T> where T: Animal<T>
{
    public T GetAnimal 
    {
        get { return (T)this; }
    }
}

public class Dog : Animal<Dog>
{
}

public class Cat : Animal<Cat>
{
}

public class Giraffe : Animal<Giraffe>
{
}
```

You call this way:

```
var cat = new Cat();
var dog = new Dog();
var giraffe = new Giraffe();
Cat cat2 = cat.GetAnimal;
Dog dog2 = dog.GetAnimal;
Giraffe giraffe2 = giraffe.GetAnimal;
```

Comment: While I think this is the best solution that C# generics gives us, just note that it is possible to do `public class Rat : Animal<Dog> { }` which will compile fine and then blow up when calling `new Rat().GetAnimal`...

Answer (score 4):

Nah you are doing it wrong.

The better thing would be to have a single method.

```
public abstract Animal getAnimal();
```

Any derived class will then know how to return itself. I hope that makes sense. But then I  don't think you would want to return an Animal either. Doesn't make sense.

```
Animal dog = new Dog() ;
dog.getAnimal();
```

confusing right?

You could have an array of Animals/List, iterate through the collection and check like so:

```
if(animal is Dog)
```

But still you are checking the type. If you want to use a base class have it so that it makes sense and exposes a common method.

Answer (score 1):

This is a really bas design since it violates the [Open-Closed principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle). You want your classes to be open for extension but closed to modification.
What will happen if tomorrow you'll want to add another class?

```
public class Donkey : Animal
{
}
```

You will have to go and change the base class so it will have a property `GetDonkey`.
You will also have to go and change all the classes that use your class and add `if (animal.GetDonkey == null)`

What you should do is use a factory design pattern like this:

```
public static class AnimalFactory
{
  public static Dog GetDog()
  {
    return new Dog();
  }

  public static Cat GetCat()
  {
    return new Cat();
  }
}
```

or you should use a virtual method like [@Lews Therin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/855421/lews-therin) suggested.

Comment: You mention there should not be a GetDonkey() but you have a GetDog()?

Answer (score -3):

It doesn't seem very useful to have properties that just return the object they're called on.

Maybe you're just looking for a way to downcast from a superclass to a subclass? If so, just use casts:

```
Animal a = new Cat();

try
{
    Dog d = (Dog)a;
}
catch (InvalidCastException)
{
    try
    {
        Cat c = (Cat)a;
    }
    catch (InvalidCastException)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use exceptions for control flow.  `is` and `as` are designed to do this without generating exceptions.

Comment: Agree with @Servy that this is a bad design. However, you can now achieve something very similar in function (without all the try/catch nonsense) utilizing switch statement pattern matching.